# delphi Spool file list

Tags: delphi

The development environment is Delphi xe2, Windows 10 64-bit.
I'm going to copy a spool file.
I installed the driver virtually on the LPT1 port. The driver is in a suspended state.
You are about to import the .spl file and the .shd file from the folder C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS.
However, it is not possible to call up a list of files in that folder.
How can I import a list into that folder?

```
function FindFiles(const sPath, sMask: string; slFiles: TStringList; bSubDir: boolean): integer;
var
  iFindResult: integer;
 srSchRec : TSearchRec;
begin
  result := 0;

  iFindResult := FindFirst(sPath + sMask, faAnyFile - faDirectory, srSchRec);
  while iFindResult = 0 do
  begin
    slFiles.Add(sPath + srSchRec.Name);
    iFindResult := FindNext(srSchRec);
  end;
  FindClose(srSchRec);

  if bSubDir then
  begin
    iFindResult := FindFirst(sPath + '*.*', faDirectory, srSchRec);
    while iFindResult = 0 do
    begin
      if (srSchRec.Name <> '.') and (srSchRec.Name <> '..') then
        result := result + FindFiles(sPath + srSchRec.Name + '\', sMask, slFiles, TRUE);
      iFindResult := FindNext(srSchRec);
    end;
    FindClose(srSchRec);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, access to `C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS` requires admin rights, this directory is protected by UAC.

So you need to run your program with elevated rights like  "run as administrator".

Comment: The same problem persisted though it was granted.